# Importing data from page running Java script (3,744 frames) with same URL into a single spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I am trying to build a mathematical model of Stock Exchange data, starting with an Excel file containing all data. I intend to import from [here](http://www.ksestocks.com/MarketSummary) since Reuters, Bloomberg, Google and Yahoo Finance do not have this data.

The website offers daily data. There are 12 years of data spread over 3,774 pages (12*312). Importing it into Excel is very time consuming. Right now what I am doing is:

1) input date on website
2) import it into Excel
3) sort and rearrange it
4) repeat the process

Is there a way I can import all data at once?

Please also advise whether MS Access would be more suitable for this.

I  later intend to process it through MATLAB Machine Learning toolbar.

the source data is from Google DOCS spread sheet

Comment: absolutely a database would be better than excel for this. even Access.

Comment: I have tried all Last night. After playing with HTML URL parameters ,I still could not get around solving the problem .I bounced from link to link until I read something on Quora about Data scrapping . I though I had Hit the mother Load with that.

So I went on Searching until I Narrowed down on Import.Io .But today after spending 3 hours with its desktop application I am still no where near scarping all the data.

Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: and Thank you DrewJordan I am gonna import the data in MS access or Matlab once I have all the data in a file.

Comment: I would use something like the "HtmlAgilityPack" with c# to automate the scraping of all of the pages. It would be far faster than trying anything manual.

Comment: I need some serious help. Its been 2 days  and I have been no where near the solution. Right now I have forgotten the original Project and totally focused on this Data Scrapping.

I have switched to a different Website. The whole Bloody website runs in a single frame.

My data is in 

http://www.kse.com.pk/ 

( Market information ---- Historical Data).

Can any body tell me which tool will be more suitable.

Comment: Enigmativity , I am ginna look into HTML agility Pack